# loading files with leading zeros in ubuntu shell (pcl_viewer example)

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, glob

i am trying to load several files in the `pcl_viewer`. But this question is more general about the Linux shell i guess. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem i have is that the filenames have many leading zeros.

The following works: `pcl_viewer fileBasename_00000[0-9].pcd`

But i cannot load files like: `fileBasename_00000[0-10].pcd.`

i have tried `fileBasename_00000[00-10].pcd` or `fileBasename_00[000-250].pcd` or `fileBasename_00[*].pcd`

Is there a space holding character which i can use to tell the shell that the filename has many leading zeros?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use bash‘s [brace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Brace_expansion) instead of [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29):

```
pcl_viewer fileBasename_00000{0..10}.pcd
```

Comment: I have a follow up question: can i somehow extend this command to just select every second file. e.g. files 2,4,...,10 ?

Comment: @Sven0 Yes, you can use `{x..y[..incr]}`, or, for your case: `{2..10..2}`.